# cin as a function argument

Tags: c++, cin, istream

I have a question in this code. What does fucntion receive when we use cin as a argument.
For example cin stops when he finds a white space or '\n', so if the input is "1 2 3 4 5" the program will return 5 but I can't understand why.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

double max_value(istream& in) // can be called with 'infile' or 'cin'
{
    double highest;
    double next;
    if (in >> next)
        highest = next;
    else
        return 0;
    while (in >> next)
    {
        if (next > highest)
            highest = next;
    }
    return highest;
}

int main()
{
    double max;
    string input; cout << "Do you want to read from a file? (y/n) ";
    cin >> input;
    if (input == "y")
    {
        string filename;
        cout << "Please enter the data file name: ";
        cin >> filename;
        ifstream infile; infile.open(filename);
        if (infile.fail())
        {
            cerr << "Error opening " << filename << "\n";
            return 1;
        }
        max = max_value(infile);
        infile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Insert the numbers. End with CTRL-Z." << endl; max = max_value(cin);
    }
    cout << "The maximum value is " << max << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Might have something to do with the concept of max. Reverse the order of the inputs and see what happens.

Comment: "*cin stops when he finds a white space or '\n'*" Yes, it stops the *current read operation* on this condition. But you do multiple read operations by using `while` loop.

Comment: There's no difference regarding whitespace depending on whether you use `cin` or `infile`. The extraction operator `>>` works the same with all `istream`s.

Comment: btw the question seems to be about the logic of that function rather than passing `cin`. You would get same output if you wrote the code of that function inline in `main`

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default initializing them and immediately overwriting the default value. In this case, that means changing `ifstream infile; infile.open(filename);` to `ifstream infile(filename);`. Also, you don't need to call `infile.close();`. The destructor will do that.